# How do I keep the camera from changing its size?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine, game-development

I have attached two screenshots to my problem. Basically on resizing the Game view window the camera size also gets resized and the objects get moved when pressing play. How do I solve this?

[image: Screenshot for view when I'm working]

[image: Screenshot for Maximized view on play]

Comment: This question most certainly has nothing to do with [tag:unityscript]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On your game view, you are in "Free Aspect" mode, which does exactly the behaviour you don't want.

You can use your standalone resolution, or define custom ones.

Answer (score 3):

Your game view is set to "Free Aspect" that mean that you do not have a screen ratio set.

I would recommend to set set it to 16:9 or 16:10 if you make a "landscape" format game because most of the screens have this kind of ratio.

[image: unity game view]

You can also define you own resolutions and test your game in different resolutions to have a preview of what your game will look like on a give screen resolution or ratio.

[image]

Free aspect is not a good choice because your camera can't scale at all.

Have a nice day

Answer (score -1):

For anybody who is suffering form the same problem, I found the solution.
You just have to download and import a free unity asset.
[Auto Letterbox](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/56814)